# Playing audio from file in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, audio, wav

.Wav files are located on the IIS server, I am reading the file name and location from DB and then I want to preview this to the user.

```
<audio controls="controls" id="auPlayer" runat="server">
  <source src="c:\mydirecotory\mysubdirec5tory.myfile.wav" type="audio/wav">

</audio>
```

Server side

```
Dim filepath as string = "c:\mydirecotory\mysubdirectory\myfile.wav"

auPlayer.InnerHtml = "<source src='" + filepath + "' type='audio/wav'/>"
```

I have checked it seems like IIS has the permission to access that directory, since IIS is writing that file there in the first place.

Comment: you have to serve that file via IIS.

Comment: is this an incorrect way to refer to a file in IIS "c:\mydirecotory\mysubdirectory\myfile.wav" ?   Should this read differently ?

Comment: it needs to be a url - that says play a file on my local computer which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you, are you saying that Audio tag is not good for my purposes ?   It is looking for that path on the client's mashine ?

Comment: the audio tag is perfect for this. its the source attribute needs to be a url.

Comment: I see, it has to read like this ?               file:///C:/temp/mydoc.txt

Comment: No - if you site is at http://example.com/page.aspx you need to use http://example.com/somePath/somefile.wav.

Comment: This is not going to work.   I have a path ServerName - C:\direcotry\subdirecotry\file.wav.   I need to load audio file from that location.  The audio player needs to be supported by all major browsers  Why am I having trouble with this ?  Guess I am missing something.  This should not be that difficult.

Comment: you aren't serving the file via a web server. there are many ways to do that.

Comment: I can try to load the wav file into a .net object, but how would I pass it to a player, when the player only accepts a URL ?

Comment: Now I can't get this working:    <embed src="..\..\directory\direcotry\Upload\0123456790_1_P.wav" type= "audio/wav" />   I get Error 503

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem, I was coding from my dev machine, I fixed the problem when I logged into the server machine.

Wrong directory was setup in IIS with APP Pool.